# Broadcast Receiver in multiple apps - services

Tags: android

I have 20 apps, installed on user device in my company. All these apps have services what are running every 50 minutes in some time period (when workers are on magazine). 
The main task of service is download json from server and execute activity. 
Question, how to not make 20 services running but if 1 service received data, notice all of them to not start? First service should be always random, first - winner.

It's actualy hard. Running 20 apps and their services will make mess in my data.

Comment: Why don't you use push notifications (FCM)?

Answer (score 0):

If the json data have a unique id attached to it, you can implement a queue system. However, it needs to be implemented on the server side, not the android app side.

Consider these steps,

1. Server generated a new json data #001.
2. *Service 1* requested a json data. Server returns the json data #001 and marked in database that *Service 1* is processing the json data #001. Btw, the database must use transaction for this to work.
3. *Service 2* requested a json data, server returns nothing because *Service 1* is marked as processing json data #001.